# Like button to a page photo

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, photo

Can you tell me with steps how can I do a like button in my site (php) to like a page photo on facebook?

I know that I have to use the GRAPH API and have to do the POST via HTTP to /likes .. but I dont know how can I do it with PHP code.

Somebody have an example?

Thank you

Comment: I am in need of a simple sample for php-sdk also, if i write one before an example is posted, i will post back.  "i will be writing this for cURL and php."

Comment: @ Fabio - i need a sample like script also. If one is not posted in timely manner i will write one.  "probaly today."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabio here is the php post snippet that i was able to get working.  Snippet includes a curl to get application access token and the api post to like an object, in this case a post on my app.

- The Sample post is here:  Shows the post to be liked

https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TimeLinePost.php?pageid=135669679827333&postid=135669679827333_151602784936066&type=feed&fh=750

- The Like Page is here: Should Return whether the user likes or not, or login if not connected.
  https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TheLike.php?postid=135669679827333_151602784936066

### **Getting the Application Access Token.**

```
function GetCH(){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS,20000);
if(substr($url,0,8)=='https://'){
    // The following ensures SSL always works. A little detail:
    // SSL does two things at once:
    //  1. it encrypts communication
    //  2. it ensures the target party is who it claims to be.
    // In short, if the following code is allowed, CURL won't check if the 
    // certificate is known and valid, however, it still encrypts communication.
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
}
$sendCH = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $sendCH;
};
$app_access_token = GetCH();
```

### **Looking in url for postid parameter then liking id**

```
  if($_GET['postid']){
  $postid = $_GET['postid'];
  }else{
  $postid = '135669679827333_151602784936066';
  }

    if($user){
 $pageLike = $facebook->api('/'.$postid.'/likes?access_token='.$access_token.'&method=post', 'POST');
}
```

Comment: I have a problem. I want do a like button to a photo in a facebook page (NOT A PROFILE) so.. what are the value that I have to change? (sorry, I'm a noob)

Comment: I dont' understand this: $_SESSION['fb_135669679827333_access_token'], I have a $_SESSION established in my site (the users have to be logged to participate in) So.. The objective is to GET the access token right?

Another thing, what is 'postid'? Where is this value?

Comment: sorry Fabio, that script will work for any object id, not just pages.  In the sample links i posted the like is pointed at wall posts and photos.

Comment: The value if the post id "in my case" is dynamic. if($_GET['postid']){} I am passing the id in the url as a parameter.

**http:// any.com ?postid=135669679827333_151602784936066** 

the SESSION or $USER prevents the pages from trying to like the object when the user is not connected to the app.  "will throw error if not connect"

Comment: Ok, now I understand a little better. So.. I have to GET the photo id to pass it in the url and then this:  $pageLike = $facebook->api('/'.$postid.'/likes?access_token='.$access_token.'&method=post', 'POST');  do the POST to like it, right?

Comment: yes that is correct.  i used 2 pages to do this, one to get my post id's then the 2nd page is in iframe which likes the id if button is pushed.  The plus to this is i can use the iframe button to like any object now, posts, photos, videos etc;

Comment: @Fabio Cardoso 

[https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TheLike.php](https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TheLike.php)
checks the like.
`echo '<iframe src="https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TheLike.php?postid='.$fvalue[id].'" style="width: 140px; height: 28px; overflow: hidden; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border: 0px solid;"></iframe><br />';`
posts the like if not liked.
`echo '<iframe src="https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TheLiked.php?postid='.$fvalue[id].'" style="width: 140px; height: 28px; overflow: hidden; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border: 0px solid;"></iframe><br />';`

Comment: It's the same code ... before "posts the like if not liked." and after it.. why? and the fvalue you get it from where? 

I can't get my system work :(

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have obtained the `publish_stream` permission from the user you can like any photo you need to. If you are attempting to like the photo as a page be sure you have an `access_token` for the page (obtained via the `/accounts` connection on the user account).

Once you have the access token the like is as simple as issuing an **HTTP POST** to a URL that looks similar to this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/likes?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

**Photo_ID** = Photo ID in Facebook

**Access_Token** = Access token obtained from Facebook with the publish_stream permission.

UPDATE

---

PHP Sample Code based on [PHP Form CURL Post](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/)

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/likes");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'Access_Token' => 'token_value'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I would check this though as I'm not sure how accurate it is since I don't normally code PHP. In any manner, the post should be a raw **HTTP POST** request.

Comment: Thank you, How Can I obtain the publish_stream, for a PHP site?

Comment: @Frazell Thomas can you possibly post the php code to issue the post?  I am having same issue and would just like to see a sample and complete curl snippet or php post script.  Anything but a copy paste info from Facebook docs.

Comment: @ShawnECarter I'm not sure how to use PHP (I'm a .NET dev), but I will see if I can find a snippet on doing a HTTP POST in PHP.

Comment: @FabioCardoso I would recommend you look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for information on how to request an extended permission.

Comment: Thank you Frazell, i was able to get using 

   if($_SESSION['fb_135669679827333_access_token']){
  $pageLike = $facebook->api('/'.$postid.'/likes?'.$app_access_token.'&method=post', 'POST');
 }

i wrapped in session to make sure the user is logged in and connected before i try to post the like object to graph.

Comment: i have tried everything to get your sample to work Frazell, just is not posting true.

Answer (score 1):

You can get permissions by building an array of perms for login url. below i am requesting read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,offline_access in the scope for permissions.

NOTE: app access token needed for logout url.

```
    <?php
    $url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        require './src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'APPID',
      'secret' => 'APP-SECRET',
      'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

            //$pageInfo = $facebook->api('/'.$pageid.'?access_token='.$_SESSION['fb_112104298812138_access_token].');
            //$pageInfoUser = $user_profile[id];
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }
    /*  */
    if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
    $params = array(
      scope => 'read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,offline_access',
      redirect_uri => $url
    );
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
    }
    $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_135669679827333_access_token'];

    ?>
<?php
        if(!$user){
    echo ' : <a href="'.$loginUrl.'" target="_self">Login</a>  ';
    }else{
        echo '<a href="'.$logoutUrl.'?'.$app_access_token.'" target="_blank">Logout</a>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: when I try your code, I get this error after click in "login" : 

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: O URL indicado não é permitido pela configuração da Aplicação.

Comment: can you link me to this test code.  That error is thrown if the page the code is on is not the domain used in the application settings.  Or you may need to use a user access token if you are liking objects not owned by the application.

Comment: I have debugged this, the URL redirect was not correct. Now it's ok, ty

Comment: awesome - this was actually hard to accomplish despite the limited amount of code needed.  In the sample i was detecting current url with php 5 for the redirect which may not work in your case.  PHP-SDK should auto detect the url if none is added.

Comment: why you don't do this: $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); instead of $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_135669679827333_access_token']; ?

Comment: Thank you fabio, i have just always requested my user session tokens that way since 3.0.0 before get was available.  :-)  think i might switch all my apps

Comment: Looks like we may have to hit this from scratch Fabio.  You can add my facebook @ facebook.com/shawnsspace - could expedite things a bit